# Bitcoind stuck: Lock table is out of available lock entries

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind

My bitcoind daemon stopped updating the blockchain at block 258354.

db.log says:

```
Lock table is out of available lock entries
Lock table is out of available lock entries
etc...
```

Here is an excerpt from debug.log:

```
ERROR: ConnectInputs() : 5915fee0a9 mapTransactions prev not found 66283c57ab
ERROR: AcceptToMemoryPool() : ConnectInputs failed 5915fee0a9
storing orphan tx 5915fee0a9
received: inv (37 bytes)
got inventory: tx 09920def2c50d6b07081  new
askfor tx 09920def2c50d6b07081   0
sending getdata: tx 09920def2c50d6b07081
sending: getdata (37 bytes) 
received: inv (37 bytes)
got inventory: tx 09920def2c50d6b07081  new
askfor tx 09920def2c50d6b07081   1379380242000000
received: inv (253 bytes)
```

Any ideas what I should do?

I just spent a week downloading the blockchain. Please not again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you updated to the latest client in the 0.8.x series? At a wild guess, it sounds like you're on 0.7.x.

Comment: I am on f**ing 0.3.24, as I just came to realize. I am running Ubuntu Precise LTS and installed simply from sources. Apparently that was a bad idea. http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/bitcoind

Comment: @Konstantin Wow, that's pretty ridiculous. What's the point of calling it LTS if they're not actually going to support it? Bitcoin releases are themselves generally supported for a long time. (I think 0.4.x is still supported by Luke-Jr in bitcoind-stable, for example.)

Comment: @theymos I am curious about that too. Maybe Ubuntu only keeps the OS updated?

Comment: Well, I think it is more of an obligation of the developers to push updates to Ubuntu instead of the Ubuntu team running after every single package to see if it got updated. I don't know what the procedure exactly is, but I've seen quite a few different packages lagging severely behind in Ubuntu comparing to their latest releases.